# Eagle: Adding thermal to QFN components

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, thermal, via, pad

How to properly place thermal vias under components?
I hook them up to the ground net, the same as the ground pad of my QFN component, but they don't seem to connect.
Do I need to edit the footprint or can I somehow just add them on the fly to my design?

[image: board photo, showing the vias under the footprint, but not connected]
I looked on google and SE, but no post seems to answer me. The question may be quite trivial, but I hope the solution speeds up work a bit.

edit:
I tried adding them to the foorprint. I made the original SMD type square pad smaller, added pads around for thermal vias and coated everything with a rectangle. All of the thermal vias and the centre pad are connected to ground GND_9. The problem is that no holes are visible in the via, so I think they won't be on the board!
[image: footprint with holes added]

Comment: Unfamiliar with eagle, but in kicad thermal vias are usually *part* of the footprint, not something you add on top of it. You'd have separate footprints for the part with or without thermal vias.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting people expierienced in Eagle design, it turns out **these thermal vias here are indeed correct**. I used KiCad and ExpressPCB before, where if the via goes all the way through, the centre of the via is black. In eagle the centre stays the same colour as the layer it's on, regardless. I'll update this post when the board arrive, then I'll be sure of this.